# Mockito + capture parameters -> retrieves the same objects multiple times

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I use Mockito and capture parameters with ArgumentCaptor as follows

```
ArgumentCaptor<MimeMessage> captorMimeMessages = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(MimeMessage.class);
verify(mockedJavaMailSender, times(4)).send(captorMimeMessages.capture());
assertEquals("blabla", captorMimeMessages.getAllValues().get(0).getSubject());
assertEquals("blabla", captorMimeMessages.getAllValues().get(1).getSubject());
etc.
```

I debugged it and the javaMailSender are called with different objects (and different subject values) four times but when I write the 4 subject values (like `System.out.println(captorMimeMessages.getAllValues().get(X).getSubject())`) in at the end of my test then I see the same (it is the subject of the last method call) subject value 4 times.

I remember I used it earlier and it worked. I use Spring, the javaMailSender is singleton, the mock is defined in the context XML like

```
<bean id="mockedJavaMailSender" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
    <constructor-arg value="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender"/>
</bean>
```

mimemessage creation:

```
    MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
    MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, false, "utf-8");
    helper.setSubject(emailSendingTask.getSubject());
    helper.setFrom(Constants.MAIL_FROM);
```

Any idea?

Comment: that is really strange. which version of mockito are you using?

Comment: How are your `MimeMessage` instances produced? By operator `new` or by mocks like `when(someMock.createObject()).thenReturn(<MimeMessage instance>)` ?

Comment: Most likely your production code stores the *subject* in a `static` *class variable*. Your test is just doing its job showing the failure...

Comment: pvpkiran: I use mockito 1.10.19.   Nikolay:I updated the ticket how the mimemessage is created.    Timothy: I kind of dislike static variables, I don't use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the following in my test class, the MimeMessage was created only once and the same instance was retrieved when I called the createMimeMessage() on my mocked javaMailSender:

```
when(mockedJavaMailSender.createMimeMessage()).thenReturn(new MimeMessage(session));
```

Instead I need the following:

```
when(mockedJavaMailSender.createMimeMessage()).then(new Answer<MimeMessage>() {
    public MimeMessage answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        return new MimeMessage(session);
    }
});
```

Comment: Great to hear that you've solved it. BTW in java 8 your code may be simplified to `when(mockedJavaMailSender.createMimeMessage()).thenAnswer(inv -> new MimeMessage(session));`

Comment: Thanks! By the way your hint led me to the solution. :)